# Not able to place elements properly after dividing them in components (Angular)

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm kinda noob on the css layout. So i had a sidebar and the app-root all placed in the index.html file as you can see in the master branch of the repository:
https://github.com/Ghevi/Angular-BugTracker/tree/master

It wasnt perfect yet but it was something: https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Itd.jpg

The navbar animations were fine and the main content moved to the right when the navbar was hovered and opened.

So then i tried to move everything in their correct components and i placed the #wrapper #left #right styling in the app.component.css to apply to in the selectors of app.component.html.

But now is more broken than ever: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LR9NP.jpg

https://github.com/Ghevi/Angular-BugTracker/tree/broken

I don't understand why other than the components beying displayed one above the other, the navbar has also missing the background color and animations now, even if i copy pasted its code in the right components.

For reference the navbar is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=biOMz4puGt8

I understand the question is loadead and a bit vague, but i'm really lost at this point.

Comment: You need to copy the stylesheet from `app.component.css` to its relevant files as well

Comment: But i dont reference those selectors in their component.html. I mean i tried but nothing changed.

Comment: You're missing the sidebar and css for the components. Can you provide the specific commits where it was working fine?

Comment: It works fine in the master branch here https://github.com/Ghevi/Angular-BugTracker/tree/master 

As you can see, i reference the navbar as id=left and the app root div as id=right all in the index.html file.

I deleted the stylesheets for navbar and header because they were also sitting in the main folder as a temporary thing. I moved their content in each components css file and deleted their reference in the index.html because now they are referenced in the component.ts decorators.

Comment: I can't seems to find `navbar` in any of the three components.

Comment: So in that branch the navbar is inside the index.html file in src. It s all that long long code before app root

Comment: You shouldn't put any `html` in your `index.html` except the links to `stylesheet` or `js`